# 'Those that couldn't let go'

Tags: grammar, pronouns

"Those that couldn't let go" is the title of a quest in an online MMPORG. Is this correct or should it be "Those whom..." or "They that ..."?

Comment: @apsillers Edited to remove invalid HTML. That might be clearer...

Comment: @AndrewLeach Aha, much clearer!

Answer (score 1):

Either ***who*** or ***that*** would be a valid [relative pronoun](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/645/01/) for the phrase. Either word can apply to people: *that* can apply to people or things, and *who* can apply only to people (or, if applied to a non-person, suggests personification).

***They*** or ***those*** would both be appropriate as well, but *those* sounds much cleaner to my American ear. "*They who...*" or "*they that...*" sounds a bit archaic, but still grammatically valid.

*Whom* is not appropriate, because *whom* must be the object of its relative clause. Here, the predicate of the relative clause is "*couldn't let go*", so relative pronoun is the subject of the clause, not the object. (The relative pronoun here refers to the acting party that couldn't let go; it is not specified as the object of any action.)